# Joining two arrays together

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'll start with the code:

```
$checkIpaddresses = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT affiliateID, source FROM am_ipaddress WHERE affiliateID = $affiliateID"));

foreach ($checkIpaddresses as $ipaddress) { 
    $ipSource = explode(",", $ipaddress->source);
}

$newIP = ",".$ipAddress;
array_push($newIP, $ipSource);

print_r($ipSource);
```

I have a column in a database with a list of IP addresses seperated by `,` (comma).  I want to be able to get that list from the database, add in a new IP address and update the column with the new list of IP addresses.

The above code is giving this error. `array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array`.

The value of `$ipAddress` is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`.

Comment: `array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array` read the error message..

Comment: You are replacing `$ipSource` for each row.

Comment: What is the type of that column?  Putting multiple values into a column is not a good idea in general; I'm particularly concerned about overflows....

Comment: I tried $newIP = array($newIP); after $newIP = ",".$ipAddress; and the result is: Array ( [0] => 1:1:1:1 [1] => 2:2:2:2 [2] => 3:3:3:3 ) - these values are already there. the current value of $ipAddress is 4:4:4:4 but it isnt adding it..

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing `$newIP = ",".$ipAddress;` ? Why not just do, `$newIP[] = $ipAddress;` ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, if this is returning only one row, you don't need a `foreach`.

```
$ipSource = explode(",", $checkIpaddresses[0]->source);  // Get the 1st row as an array
```

Second, you are over-complicating adding the new IP address to the array.

```
$ipSource[] = $ipAddress;
```

That's it.  Now the `$ipSource` array contains the new IP address.

(P.S. Use `implode(',', $ipSource)` to turn the array into a comma-separated string)